# My Minecraft skin is not showing properly in game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open Minecraft it shows the skin properly in the launcher but when I view myself in the game it doesn't show my clothing, only the layer that was put on behind it. Any advice?

Skin from the launcher:
[image: .]

Skin in-game:

[image: .]

Comment: Do you mean that your "hat" (the extra skin layer on the player's head) and "jacket" (the extra skin layer on the player's torso) layers of your skin aren't displaying properly?

Comment: Go to Options then Skin settings and turn on the layers from that settings screen. Commenting because I am unsure about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my Minecraft skin overlay not display in-game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/230231/why-does-my-minecraft-skin-overlay-not-display-in-game)

Answer (score -2):

This is Minecraft Specialist Joseph Casey(TheBigJoe1489) Here.

Problem: Skin wont show in world/Will show in launcher.

Advice: Try to make an ALT skin, and try that. If that doesnt work, consult Mojang about it, it may be a Bug in Minecraft, it has happened to me when my minecraft arm got pinned behind my back on PS4 edition and I had to leave the game and go back.

Hope this helps.